# How to set UIButton type?

Tags: iphone, uibutton

A small - little question.

I have seen many application having buttons like following.
[image]

While using Interface builder I didn't Found any option to have this kind of button.
How to have this kind of button in your application.

Comment: I've got a blog entry demonstrating how to make shiny buttons with `CAGradientLayer`: [Shiny iPhone Buttons Without Photoshop](http://undefinedvalue.com/2010/02/27/shiny-iphone-buttons-without-photoshop)

Comment: I find this method much better. No need to create images that use up memory.

Comment: The CAGradientLayer uses memory. I don't know how it compares to the size of a loaded image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See UICatalog example -> Buttons. You will find there this kind of buttons. Usually they're done using png images for pressed & normal states. I think you can do it in IB by binding a png image to pressed & normal states, but the example in UICatalog is pretty clear and can be used "as is"

Comment: Before you answered me, I downloaded the same sample code & I was going to post my own answer. But you have already posted it. +1 for your reaction timing - "Sir". & for giving me correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Almost invariably these styles are done using bitmap images or for the more thrifty of memory, [CAGradientLayer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html).

To do it with CAGradientLayer, you would do something very much like the way the [gradient and shadows are done in this blog entry](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/08/adding-shadow-effects-to-uitableview.html).

Comment: Excellent Sample Code - Great help to me.

Comment: You're not going to save any memory doing this, since the CAGradientLayer has a bitmap at its core anyway.